# Android with Javacv error when running in Portrait mode

Tags: opencv, javacv, android, cascade-classifier

I am working on an Android application that has face detection feature. I am using javacv to achieve this. When I run the application in landscape mode it works fine. But when I run the application in the portrait mode, I get "**OpenCV Error: Parsing error (/data/data/com.example.learning/cache/lbph.yml(1270): Bad format of floating-point constant) in void icvProcessSpecialDouble(CvFileStorage*, char*, double*, char**), file /home/saudet/projects/javacv-cppjars/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp**".

I get this error when I am trying to load the classifier (from the res/raw directory).

How to resolve this issue ?